# How to find element with "== $0" after end tag in html using Xpath, css or any other locators in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[the html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL4Sf.png)

```html
<div class=""><div>Bengaluru, Karnataka</div></div>
```

Consider the above example for reference.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work!!!

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class=""]').text.strip()

Comment: Please can you share the page or the piece of html you want to get?

Comment: Yes I want to get the text from the html tag

Comment: `<div class=""><div>Bengaluru, Karnataka</div></div>` or `<div class><div>Bengaluru, Karnataka</div></div>`? Is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not filter by that "==$0"

But you can use this xpath, which will return to you the element with following requirements:

- It is a "div"
- That "div" contains an attribute "class"
- That "class" attribute has a length of 0 chars

This is the xpath:

```
//div[@class[string-length()=0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='']/div").text
```

Output:

```
Bengaluru, Karnataka
```